# ¿Cómo puedo agregar la clase error y limitar caracteres?

Tags: html, jquery, css3

El código me controla de que el número de carácteres no sea mayor a 80 pero no me está funcionando para que si se pasa del número de caracteres muestre el borde rojo agregando una clase al textarea y si me devuelvo debe de desaparecer esa clase. Igual dene pasar lo mismo con el contador.

[image: Debe quedar como aparece en la imagen]

Este es el código que tengo:

---

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Contador de caracteres</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <textarea rows="3"></textarea>
    <div class="counter">0</div>
  </div>
  <!-- incluye jQuery y crea la referencia a app.js -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

### style.css

```
.container {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 30px auto;
}

textarea {
  background-color: #f5f5f2;
  color: #707068;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #B5B5A8;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.counter {
  color: #666;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: right;
}

.error textarea {
  border-color: red;
  border-width: 5px;
}

.error .counter {
  color: red;
}
```

---

### app.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var max_chars = 80;

    $('textarea').keyup(function() {
        var chars = $(this).val().length;
        var diff = max_chars - chars;
        $('.counter').html(chars); 
        if(chars >= 80){
           $('textarea').addClass('error');
           $('.counter').addClass('error');
           $('textarea').attr("maxlength", max_chars);
          }
        $('textarea').removeClass('error')
         $('.counter').removeClass('error')

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En su código en la sección de `Js` , sí añade la clase error a los elementos pero luego los elimina lo cuál es incorrecto, La solución más sencilla sería el  emplear [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) pasando le como segundo parámetro la condición *(se puede hacer referencia al textarea con la palabra reservada this)*  , Además tener cuidado con la línea `$('textarea').attr("maxlength", max_chars);`  hará que ya no se pueda ingresar más caracteres. También podría tener solo una clase error que aplique el `border` y el color al texto.

```js
$(function() {
  var max_chars = 80;
    $('textarea').keyup(function() {
        var chars = $(this).val().length;
        var diff = max_chars - chars;
        $('.counter').html(chars); 
        $(this).toggleClass('error',chars>=80);
        $('.counter').toggleClass('error',chars>=80);
    });
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 30px auto;
}
textarea {
  background-color: #f5f5f2;
  color: #707068;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #B5B5A8;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.counter {
  color: #666;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: right;
}
.error {
  border-color: red;
  border-width: 5px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <textarea rows="3"></textarea>
  <div class="counter">0</div>
</div>
```

También tendría la opción de emplear [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) para hacer el `toggle` de la clase cuando se cumpla la condición.

```
   this.classList.toggle("error", chars >= 80 ); 
   document.querySelectorAll('.counter')[0].classList.toggle("error", chars >= 80 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Realmente veo tres problemas en tu código:

- Si quieres que la clase `.error` se combine con el elemento `textarea` o con la clase `.counter` deberías de ponerlo así en el css:

  ```
  .counter.error{
      //Tus propiedades CSS aquí
  }
  ```

  **Ten en cuenta que no hay ningún espacio entre ambas clases.**
- En el Javascript tendrías que controlar que si la longitud del string es menor a 80 quite las clases mediante la sentencia `else`.
- Le estás asignando una longitud máxima al textarea por lo que no podrás ver los dígitos que te estás pasando en el texto. Deberías de quitar la línea:

  ```
  $('textarea').attr("maxlength", max_chars);
  ```

Tu ejemplo modificado:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    var max_chars = 80;

    $('#max').html(max_chars);

    $('textarea').keyup(function() {
        var chars = $(this).val().length;
        var diff = max_chars - chars;
        $('.counter').html(chars); 
        if(chars >= 80){
           $('textarea').addClass('error');
           $('.counter').addClass('error');
          }else{
            $('textarea').removeClass('error');
            $('.counter').removeClass('error');
          }
    });
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 30px auto;
}

textarea {
  background-color: #f5f5f2;
  color: #707068;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #B5B5A8;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.counter {
  color: #666;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: right;
}

textarea.error  {
  border-color: red;
  border-width: 5px;
}

.counter.error{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <textarea rows="3"></textarea>
  <div class="counter">0</div>
</div>
```